# Rails: How to make recent blog posts appear first

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm creating a blog app with ruby on rails. I was able to allow a user to add posts, but on the top of the page, the posts that were created first appear first. I want the most recent blog posts to appear first. How do I do this? Let me know which code files I need to add here.

my articles controller

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
    def new
        @article = Article.new
    end

     def index
      @articles = Article.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
     end

    def show
       @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def create
        @article = Article.new(article_params)

        @article.save
        redirect_to @article
    end

    def edit
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
    end

    def update
        @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        if @article.update(article_params)
            redirect_to @article
        else
            render 'edit'
        end

    end

    def destroy
         @article = Article.find(params[:id])
        @article.destroy

        redirect_to articles_path
    end
end

private
def article_params
    params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text, :datee)
end
```

Comment: Do as @Rockwell Rice suggested.  By default they will be listed in ascending order unless you specify otherwise by changing the scope.

Answer (score 9):

I would set a default scope in the model, you could just use `order` but this is how I like to do it because I typically always want that order applied and this way I do not have to keep using `order`. Put this in your model and it should reorder them.

article.rb

```
# Scopes
default_scope {order(created_at: :desc)}
```

With a default scope set no further action is needed articles will default to that order.

**If you do not want it to default to that order** all of the time you can just make a regular scope to call.

article.rb

```
scope :recent_first, -> {order(created_at: :desc)}
```

and then in the Index action you would just use

```
def index
  @articles = Article.recent_first.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

If you really only need to do this in this one spot `order`, as Adam Lassek mentions in his comment below, works as well.

```
def index
  @articles = Article.order(created_at: desc).paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

Comment: While I am less of a hard-liner about `default_scope` than many, this is not a situation where I would recommend its use. The potential for confusion is high, since this default order will be tacked onto every `order` scope that is called against it, whereas simply adding `order(created_at: desc)` is just not that big a deal here.

Answer (score 2):

Add new scope into `Article` model:

```
class Article < ApplicationRecord    
  scope :ordered, -> { order(created_at: :desc) }
end
```

Use the scope in the controller:

```
def index
  @articles = Article.ordered.paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Or you can simply do this.

```
 def index
  @articles = Article.order('created_at desc').paginate(:page => params[:page], :per_page => 10)
 end
```